# Typescript mapped type where only nullable properties are retained and converted to string type

Tags: typescript, nullable, mapped-types

I'm trying to create a new mapped type from an existing type. I'm looking to replace all nullable properties with a `string` type. Basic idea is to have the mapped type replace all nullable property types in sub-records with a `string` type. If the sub-record doesn't include any nullable types the sub-record itself is excluded from the mapped type. Also any property that is not an object is excluded.

```
interface OriginalType {
    foo: {
        bar: string | null;
        baz: number | null;
    };
    bar: {
        qux: string;
        quz: boolean | null;
        wobble: string | null;
    };
    baz: {
        grault: string;
        garply: number;
        flob: boolean;
    };
    version: number;
}

interface ExpectedType {
    foo: {
        bar: string;
        baz: string;
    };
    bar: {
        quz: string;
        wobble: string;
    };
}
```

I currently have written this mapped type so far:

```
type RetainNullablesAsString<T> = {
    [C in keyof T]: T[C] extends object ? {
        [K in keyof T[C]]: null extends T[C][K] ? string : never;
    }: never;
}
```

If testing it I get an error:

> Property 'qux' is missing in type '{ quz: string; wobble: string; }' but required in type '{ qux: never; quz: string; wobble: string; }'.

I intend the `qux` property to be excluded from the type as it's not nullable but I don't know how to do that - I currently set it to `never` in the mapped type. The Pick utility type would't be of help here I think as I don't want to hardcode any properties to the mapped type. Also the `baz` record should be excluded as all of it's child properties are not nullable. Moreover I don't know if it's even possible to create a mapped type like this but would be glad if it was.

```js
interface OriginalType {
    foo: {
        bar: string | null;
        baz: number | null;
    };
    bar: {
        qux: string;
        quz: boolean | null;
        wobble: string | null;
    };
    baz: {
        grault: string;
        garply: number;
        flob: boolean;
    };
    version: number;
}
  
const sourceRecord: OriginalType = {
    foo: {
        bar: 'bar',
        baz: 0,
    },
    bar: {
        qux: 'qux',
        quz: false,
        wobble: null,
    },
    baz: {
        grault: 'grault',
        garply: 1,
        flob: true,
    },
    version: 1,
}

//interface ExpectedType {
//    foo: {
//        bar: string;
//        baz: string;
//    };
//    bar: {
//        quz: string;
//        wobble: string;
//    };
//}

type RetainNullablesAsString<T> = {
    [C in keyof T]: T[C] extends object ? {
        [K in keyof T[C]]: null extends T[C][K] ? string : never;
    }: never;
}

const sourceRecordMetaData: RetainNullablesAsString<OriginalType> = {
    foo: {
        bar: 'bar-meta',
        baz: 'baz-meta',
    },
    bar: {
        quz: 'quz-meta',
        wobble: 'wobble-meta',
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
interface OriginalType {
    foo: {
        bar: string | null;
        baz: number | null;
    };
    bar: {
        qux: string;
        quz: boolean | null;
        wobble: string | null;
    };
    baz: {
        grault: string;
        garply: number;
        flob: boolean;
    };
    version: number;
}

type IsNullableProperty<K extends keyof T, T> = null extends T[K] ? K : never;

// Filtering out non nullable properties and convert rest to strings
type ConvertSubRecord<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as IsNullableProperty<K, T>]: string;
};

type IsEmptyObject<T> = keyof T extends never ? never : T;

// It transform property keys for non records and records that are converted into empty objects into never
type IsNotEmptySubRecord<K extends keyof T, T> = T[K] extends object
    ? keyof ConvertSubRecord<T[K]> extends never
    ? never
    : K
    : never;

type Convert<T> = {
    // Filter out with IsNotEmptySubRecord helper and convert subrecords with ConvertSubRecord
    [K in keyof T as IsNotEmptySubRecord<K, T>]: ConvertSubRecord<T[K]>;
};

interface ExpectedType {
    foo: {
        bar: string;
        baz: string;
    };
    bar: {
        quz: string;
        wobble: string;
    };
}

const res: Convert<OriginalType> = {
    bar: {
        quz: "",
        wobble: ""
    },
    foo: {
        bar: "",
        baz: "",
    },
}
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know you could set record keys as `never`. This is basically what I was missing.