Is it possible to make all optional properties of typescript interface accept null?
I have a interface defined as
interface IExample {
  property1: string;
  property2: number;
  property3?: number;
  property4?: string;
}

How do I make all optional properties accept null? I don't want to add null to each optional property
I tried creating this type but this this does not work
  type SetOptionalKeysNullable<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends undefined ? undefined | null : T[K];
  };



Seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68713907/typescript-mapped-type-where-only-nullable-properties-are-retained-and-converted

Detecting optional properties requires something other than just checking for undefined.  See this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Thanks, this is what i ideally wanted. Works as expected. Just wondering can we make it recursive so that the nested fields also behave the same

The best way to detect optional properties is to use the (unsafe but convenient) assignability of a missing property to an optional property to a missing property. That is, {} is assignable to {a?: string}, but not to {a: string} or to {a: string | undefined}.  Any checking that just looks at undefined will end up being unable to distinguish optional properties from required properties that expect undefined.  So for each property K in keyof T, if {} is assignable to Pick<T, K>, then K is optional in T:
type SetOptionalKeysNullable<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] | ({} extends Pick<T, K> ? null : never)
};

Let's test it out:
interface IExample {
  property1: string;
  property2: number;
  property3?: number;
  property4?: string;
}    
type ExOut = SetOptionalKeysNullable<IExample>;
/* type ExOut = {
    property1: string;
    property2: number;
    property3?: number | null | undefined;
    property4?: string | null | undefined;
} */

// none of these properties are optional
type Also = SetOptionalKeysNullable<{
  a: string; 
  b: string | null;
  c: string | undefined;
}>
type AlsoOut = SetOptionalKeysNullable<Also>;
/* type AlsoOut = {
    a: string;
    b: string | null;
    c: string | undefined;
} */

Looks good. All of the optional properties get null added to their domain, whereas nothing happens to any of the required properties.
Playground link to code

You can refer to Partial source code：
type Partial<T> = {                 
     [P in keyof T]?: T[P];              
 };

Define your own interface PartialMayBeNull：
type PartialMayBeNull<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] | null
}

Useage:
const example: PartialMayBeNull<IExample> = {
  property1: null,
  property2: null,
}

If you want to make the property optional and can be null, Modify the above implementation:
type PartialMayBeNull<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P] | null
}

Sorry, I overlooked that this would affect the required properties, modify as follows

interface IExample {
  property1: string
  property2: number
  property3?: number
  property4?: string
}

type IsPartialProperty<K extends keyof T, T> = undefined extends T[K] ? K : never
type IsRequiredProperty<K extends keyof T, T> = undefined extends T[K] ? never : K

type PartialProperties<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as IsPartialProperty<K, T>]: T[K] | null
}
type RequiredProperties<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as IsRequiredProperty<K, T>]: T[K]
}
type PartialMayBeNull<T> = PartialProperties<T> & RequiredProperties<T>

const example: PartialMayBeNull<IExample> = {
  property1: 'foo',
  property2: null, // Error: Type null is not assignable to type number
  property3: null, // No error
}


This also affects the non-optional properties

This would make all properties nullable, not just the optional ones

The answer was modified by referring to another question

In {x: string | undefined}, x is not an optional property, but this code will treat it as such.

  type SetOptionalKeysNullable<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends NonNullable<T[K]>
      ? T[K]
      : T[K] | null | undefined;
  };

This is what worked for me

What does it do for {a: string | null, b: number | undefined}? Neither of those are optional properties, but your code would add undefined to the first one and null to the second.
